# A die is rolled and a coin is flipped. What is wrong with the following reasoning?

Tags: probability, dice, independence

A die is rolled and a coin is flipped. What is wrong with the following reasoning?:

Let $A=\{1,3,6\}$ (event from die roll), let $B=\{H\}$ (event of heads)
then, $A\cap B=\emptyset$ (since they have no common elements)
and $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(\emptyset)=0$.

I realize that the probability of the intersection of two independent events is the product of their probabilities but I want to know what is 'wrong' with this reasoning.

Comment: You’re looking at the wrong event space(s).

Comment: Long story short, $A, B$ are not events themselves, but *images* of events as mapped by two different functions.

Comment: You are purely looking at sets, not events. Things change if you wonder wether the "event" that a die takes a value in $\{1,3,6\}$ and the "event" that a coin flipping results in a head can go together. These events are evidently not mutually exclusive. This must also come forward in our mathematical model of the reality.

Comment: Note that your reasoning would be correct if the original problem statement had been "a die is rolled **or** a coin is flipped", in which case H and 1, 3, 6 would indeed be mutually exclusive possibilities.

Answer (score 30):

The problem is the wrong choice of sample space.

The right sample space is $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \times\{H,T\}$ note that the elementary events are ordered pairs $(\omega_1, \omega_2)$.

Now consider the events

\begin{align*}
E_1&=\{(\omega_1, \omega_2) \in \Omega: \omega_1\in\{1,3,6\}\}\\
E_2&=\{(\omega_1, \omega_2) \in \Omega: \omega_2=H\}\,.
\end{align*}

You should be able to say what $P(E_1 \cap E_2)$ is, and it's not $0$.

---

Suppose $P$ is the uniform probability.

$$P(E_1  \cap E_2)=\frac{|E_1 \cap E_2|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{3}{12}=0.25\,.$$

Answer (score 5):

Events are sets of outcomes.   $\{1,3,6\}$ and $\{\mathcal H\}$ are sets of *measures of* outcomes.   The values of a die roll, and the enumerations of a coin toss.   They are images of events, not the events *per se*.

The event you want is not the union of these sets, but the intersection of their *preimages* as mapped by appropriate random variables.

That is, if we let *random variable* $X$ be the result of the die roll, and $Y$ be the result of the coin toss, then the event you want is: $X^{-1}\{1,3,6\}~\cap~Y^{-1}\{\mathcal H\}$.

We might choose to *describe* the outcomes of the process as ordered lists of such measures.   In which case $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}{\times}\{\mathcal H,\mathcal T\}$ is *a* sensible representation<sup>†</sup> for a *sample space*.   It is the set of *all* discernible results of rolling a die *and* tossing a coin.

$$\begin{align}X^{-1}\{1,3,6\}~\cap~Y^{-1}\{\mathcal H\}~&=~\{\omega\in\Omega : (X(\omega)\in\{1,3,6\})\wedge (Y(\omega)\in\{\mathcal H\})\} \\[1ex] &=~ \big\{(1,\mathcal H),(3,\mathcal H),(6,\mathcal H)\big\}\end{align}$$

$\begin{align}\\[10ex]\color{silver}{\tiny\dagger\text{ Technically this is still also only a map of the sample space, but let us not fall too far down the rabbit hole.}}\end{align}$

Comment: Why $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \times \{H,T\}$ is not a sample space in a tecnically point of view?

Comment: It's a perfectly fine sample space. The statement is incorrect.

Comment: It may appear so from textbooks, but there is nothing in probability theory mandating that sample spaces be vast wastelands populated only by amorphous, faceless little omegas. They can be ordinary, explicitly constructed, finite sets if that's all your situation requires.

Comment: Hey, I don’t want to start an edit war, and I see you’ve already reverted someone else’s attempt to fix this, but: that footnote text is too small and too lightly colored. The contrast ratio is only 1.82, while WAI-ARIA mandates a contrast ratio of at least 3 at that size. Please consider rolling back to revision 3. Not everyone has excellent vision, and I simply cannot read the text in your post. I only noticed that it was there because of the giant gap above it, and then had to copy-and-paste it into an external buffer to see what it said. There is no reason for this to be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to say sensible things about the probability that the die shows a face in $\{1,3,6\}$ **and** a flipped coin shows head we must first construct a suitable model for the situation.

This usually is done by means of a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $\langle\Omega,\mathcal F,P\rangle$ together with functions $X:\Omega\to\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $Y:\Omega\to\{H,T\}$.

In this context $\mathcal F$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ that meets specific conditions. Elements of $\Omega$ are **outcomes** and and elements of $\mathcal F$ are **events**.

In our example the sets $A=\{1,3,6\}$ and $B=\{H\}$ induce the events:

- $\{X\in A\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in A\}$
- $\{Y\in B\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega)\in B\}$

Note that nothing points is the direction that the events $\{X\in A\}$ and $\{Y\in B\}$ should have an empty intersection.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand note:
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)=P(A)\cdot P(B)=\frac{3}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}.$$
The thing is this is a two step experiment with the first step of rolling a die and the second step of flipping a coin. The counting rule of the total number of experimental outcomes of the multiple step experiment is to multiply the numbers of outcomes in each step. In this case it is:
$$n(S)=n_1\cdot n_2=6\cdot 2=12.$$
Thus, all expermental outcomes make up the sample space, from which one should form the events (or subsets of the sample space). In your case, you should have:
$$X=\{1H,3H,6H\}, P(X)=\frac{n(X)}{n(S)}=\frac{3}{12}=\frac{1}{4}.$$
Note that all outcomes are equally likely.

Also one can form an event from within each step, however the intersection of the events of distinct steps in probability theory imply coexisting outcomes (unlike in set theory common elements). Moreover, the events or outcomes within a step can be mutually exclusive or not, while across steps dependent or independent. Thus, in the case of rolling a die and flipping a coin, the events $A$ and $B$ are across steps and independent.